# fillna() method does not replace values in data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I need to replace the values inside the dataset, I used the fillna() method, the function runs, but when I check the data is still null

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('mamografia.csv')
dataset

mamografia = dataset
mamografia

malignos = mamografia[mamografia['Severidade'] == 0].isnull().sum()
print('Valores ausentes: ')
print()
print('Valores Malignos: ', malignos)
print()
belignos = mamografia[mamografia['Severidade'] == 1].isnull().sum()
print('Valores Belignos:', belignos)

def substitui_ausentes(lista_col):
     for lista in lista_col:
         if lista != 'Idade':
             mamografia[lista].fillna(value = mamografia[lista][(mamografia['Severidade'] == 0)].mode())
             mamografia[lista].fillna(value = mamografia[lista][(mamografia['Severidade'] == 1)].mode())
         else:
             mamografia[lista].fillna(value = mamografia[lista][(mamografia['Severidade'] == 0)].mean())
             mamografia[lista].fillna(value = mamografia[lista][(mamografia['Severidade'] == 1)].mean())             

mamografia.columns

substitui_ausentes(mamografia.columns)


mamografia
```

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to replace the null values, using fillna()

Answer (score 1):

By default `fillna` does not work in place but returns the result of the operation.

You can either set the new value manually using

```
df = df.fillna(...)
```

Or overwrite the default behaviour by setting the parameter `inplace=True`

```
df.fillna(... , inplace=True)
```

However your code will still not work since you want to fill the different severities separately.

Since the function is being rewritten lets also make it more pandonic by not making it change the Dataframe by default

```
def substitui_ausentes(dfc, reglas, inplace = False):
    if inplace: 
        df = dfc
    else:
        df = dfc.copy()
    fill_values = df.groupby('Severidade').agg(reglas).to_dict(orient='index')
    for k in fill_values:
        df.loc[df['Severidade'] == k] = df.loc[df['Severidade'] == k].fillna(fill_values[k])
    return df
```

Note that you now need to call the function using

```
reglas = {
    'Idade':lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0],
    'Densidade':'mean'
}
substitui_ausentes(df,reglas, inplace=True)
```

and the `reglas` dictionary needs to include only the columns you want to fill and how you want to fill them.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll update the code, I'll see if it went right. Return to you.